# How to design a schema model for different users

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to mongodb and I'm working on my personal project which is a project management system for college projects. I have 3 users admin(the department), students, and advisor. The admin is the one who registers both the students and the advisors. All the users have some common fields like name, email, and password. And different fields of there own.

Their roles:-

```
- Admin -> adds the students and advisors
- Student -> choose projects and work on the projects in a team
- Advisor -> advice students based on their progress on their project
```

- My problem is in designing the model should I use one userSchema and add all the users in one collection or create different collections for each user.
- My second confusion is if I create different collections for each user how can I deal with authentication and authorization? I'm using node js for the backend.

**Can I get some guidance and suggestion?**

Answer (score 0):

It's your choice.
Here, I would suggest to use a single Collection for all the 3 types of Users.
Since everyone would be having same functionalities like  name, email, password etc. on registration, single Schema would work for sure.

So create on schema of suppose 'User' and then use one 'tag' selector to identify the admin, advisor and student.

I would do something like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
tag : {
type: String
},
    
  Addtasks: [
    {
      topic: String,
      words: Number,
      keywords: String,
      website: String,
      otherdetails: String,
      exampleRadios: String,
      deadline: Date,
      Date: String,
      fileName: String
    },
  ],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

With this create one page for authentication as `auth.js` separately and write the single authentication code there using passport module authentication. With that said now you can use one authentication validation for all 3 dashboards.

For handlebars as front-end use this to check the user if he/she has logged in or not.

```
{{if #user}}
<html>
<head>
.
.
.
...
```

following this you can achieve this.